# How do I get apple touch icons accessible from an https MVC application?

Tags: ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an MVC application hosted on a secure instance of IIS.  So the URL is similar to https://test.apps.com/TestApp.  In the images folder I have all my Apple, Android, Windows, etc. icons that I generated from http://realfavicongenerator.net/.  The problem is when I browse to the site from iOS and try to "Add to Home Screen" it just uses a screen shot.  If I try this from a server without security then it works correctly.

The following is in my head section:

```
<!-- realfavicongenerator.net -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="@Url.Content("~/images/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png?3")">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="@Url.Content("~/images/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png?3")">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="@Url.Content("~/images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png?3")">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="@Url.Content("~/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png?3")">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="@Url.Content("~/images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png?3")">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="@Url.Content("~/images/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png?3")">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="@Url.Content("~/images/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png?3")">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="@Url.Content("~/images/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png?3")">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="@Url.Content("~/images/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png?3")">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@Url.Content("~/images/favicon-32x32.png?3")" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@Url.Content("~/images/android-chrome-192x192.png?3")" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@Url.Content("~/images/favicon-96x96.png?3")" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@Url.Content("~/images/favicon-16x16.png?3")" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="@Url.Content("~/images/manifest.json?3")">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="@Url.Content("~/images/safari-pinned-tab.svg?3")" color="#5bbad5">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content("~/images/favicon.ico?3")">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="@Url.Content("~/images/mstile-144x144.png")">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="@Url.Content("~/images/browserconfig.xml")">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Here is what I have tried so far.

1) In Windows giving "everyone" read access to the images folder.

2) In applicationHost.config on the server changing this to Allow.

```
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

3) In my web.config adding the following:

```
<location path="images">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="images">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

4) A couple more tweaks

```
<location path="images" allowOverride="false">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" username="" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

All to no avail.

Here are some links that I got this information from.

[Allow anonymous authentication for a single folder in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config)

[Allow anonymous user to browse the Style and Images folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391053/allow-anonymous-user-to-browse-the-style-and-images-folder)

[Authorize a directory for anonymous users IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901587/authorize-a-directory-for-anonymous-users-iis-7-5)

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Do you have a `link` tag on the page to reference the icon?  Show that code.

Comment: Good point.  This has been added.